# Angular2: Percent Pipe Not Working When Model Changed to Same Value

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

I am using p-dataTable from primefaces. When I first loaded the values, the percent pipe works. Say the value of field1 = 0.1, it displays 10%. When I change the value from 10% and typed 20, the pipe changes it to 20%. Now the problem is, when I typed 20 again, the pipe now doesn't format to 20%.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="myValue">
    <p-column field="field1" header="field1">
        <template let-col let-can="rowData" let-index="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
            <input value="{{can[col.field]|percent}}" (change)="onCellChange($event.target.value, col.field, index)"/>
        </template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

The typescript:

```
onCellChange(value: number, field: string, index: number) {
    this.myValue[index][field] = value / 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use binding with square brackets instead of expression.

```
<input [value]="can[col.field]|percent" (change)="onCellChange($event.target.value, col.field, index)"/>
```

Comment: I tried this as well but it doesn't solve my problem. Thanks anyway.